# Security Error in WMI Connection

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, wmi, remote-access

When trying to fetch running process details from a Windows 2008 server, I get the error code -2147217405 (0x80041003). I've read that it's a security issue. I'm connecting using a C++ MFC dialog-based application and have performed the following steps:

1. `CoInitializeEx()`
2. `CoInitializeSecurity()`
3. `CoCreateInstance()`
4. `CoSetProxyBlanket()`

```cpp
hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
            pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
            RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT,         // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
            RPC_C_AUTHZ_DEFAULT,         // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
            COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL,      // Server principal name 
            RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx
            RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
            NULL,                        // client identity
            EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities
        );
```

I haven't used the `COAUTHIDENTITY` structure to provide credentials for setting the proxy security.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(pSvc,            
                                           RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT,
                                           RPC_C_AUTHZ_DEFAULT,
                                           COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL,
                                           RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,
                                           RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
                                           NULL,
                                           EOAC_NONE
                                   );

Comment: The error is [`WBEM_E_ACCESS_DENIED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394559#WBEM_E_ACCESS_DENIED), which is described as the "[c]urrent user does not have permission to perform the action".

Comment: But when I use some other WMI tool which I got from Internet to connect to the same server using same credentials its gives me complete information.